# Qt-QString в int

Tags: c++, qt, дата, qstring

Как конвертировать:

```
QString test="12.09.2019";
```

в integer? Есть ли в Qt функция atoi?

UPD: в С++(без QT) я мог конвертировать таким способом:

```
int day=atoi(&str1[0]);
      int month=atoi(&str1[3]);
      int year=atoi(&str1[6]);
```

Comment: И какое число должно получиться из этой строки? Для простых случаев в `QString` имеются функции-члены `toInt`, `toLong`, `toDouble`, и т.д. Они чем-то не устраивают? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html

Comment: Дату в число? Вам нужен timestamp?

Comment: мне нужно конветрировать это число и потом сравнить ифом

Comment: @Croessmah было бы хорошо ковертировать эту строку в int day, int month, int year ;чтоб потом мог сравнивать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы дату в число, нужно:

- Распарсить строку с датой, например [QDateTime::fromString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#fromString-1)
- Получить timestamp (секунды от 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000) используя [QDateTime::toSecsSinceEpoch](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toSecsSinceEpoch)

Пример:

```
QString test = "12.09.2019";
QDateTime dt = QDateTime::fromString(test, "dd.MM.yyyy");
qint64 secs = dt.toSecsSinceEpoch();
```

---

**UPD.** если нужно просто поработать с датой, то есть `QDate`:

```
QString test = "12.09.2019";
QDate d = QDate::fromString(test, "dd.MM.yyyy");
d.day()   // 12
d.month() // 9
d.year()  // 2019
```

---

Можно и парсить строку через [QString::split](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#split), пример:

```
QString test = "12.09.2019";
QStringList parts = str.split('.');
// parts : [ "12", "09", "2019"]
int day = parts[0].toInt();   // 12
int month = parts[1].toInt(); // 9
int year = parts[2].toInt();  // 2019
```

Comment: Как можно сравнить эту дату(test)  с текущей ?

Comment: Просто сравниваете `d` с текущей датой: `if (d == QDate::currentDate()) { ...` У дат операторы сравнения переопределены. Можно еще обе даты в timestamp переводить, или вручную сравнивать их год, месяц и день, но это извращения -- операторов сравнения хватит

Comment: можно у вас что-то спросить в вк?я вам заявку скинул :)

Comment: @RoarRaizZer, я там не сижу, да и нет желания общаться, спрашивайте тут :)

Comment: Хотелось бы лично. :)

Comment: @RoarRaizZer, у меня есть почта, на профиле гитхаба